# Algorithm - Colour surrounded by another colour in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, breadth-first-search

I recently faced this problem in an interview:

Given below matrix:

```
[[ R R R R R R],
 [ R B B B R R],
 [ B R R R B B],
 [ R B R R R R]]
```

Find out if any group of *only R's* or *only B's* surrounded by Opposite colour in the 4 directions: up, down, left, right corners.

ex: Answer for the above matrix -> Valid set of B's surrounded by R's in the second row.

```
[[ R R R R R R],
 [ R **B B B** R R],
 [ B R R R B B],
 [ R B R R R R]]
```

I tried doing a BFS for a specific colour in all directions but was unable to come up to solution.
Can someone guide me to the solution.

Comment: Do the boundaries of the matrix count as a valid surrounding? Say, covered 3 sides by `R` but the fourth side hits a boundary.

Comment: The group only occupies one line or can occupy more lines? Does it have to be straight or be a crossed group, for instance? There are details missing

Comment: You can get all groups in O(m*n) using flooding algorithm. All groups with no element touching the border are automatically solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the groups of B cells surrounded by R cells, think of the matrix as a graph whose vertices are all the B cells, with edges connecting adjacent B cells. Use BFS (or DFS) to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms) of this graph, but ignore the connected components that contain cells on the boundary. Each (non-boundary) connected component contains a set of B cells surrounded by R cells. Then, to find the groups of R cells surrounded by B cells, similarly compute the non-boundary connected components of the graph whose vertices are the R cells.

Since the number of vertices and edges of both graphs is `O(mn)` and the set of connected components of a graph can be found in time that is linear in the graph's size, the running time of this algorithm is `O(mn)`.