# How to make the green boxes filling the whole screen without clicking on each single square?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, motionevent

I wanna smooth movement (non-linear) to active all the spots on the screen below without clicking on each single square. It is working only when I click cell by cell, but when I try to move in loopy directions, it does not select the empty boxes.

Here is my current code:

```java
@Override
public void onItemTouched(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (view.getTextAlignment() == View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct));
                view.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
                contTouchCounter += 2;
                Log.i(TAG, "onItemTouched: " + contTouchCounter);
            }

            if (contTouchCounter == 100) {
                disposable.dispose();
                linearContTouch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cont_touch.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_circle_outline_24));
                cont_touchTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                multimediaInfo.setContTouch(String.valueOf(contTouchCounter));
                isContTouchStarted = false;
                goToNextActivity();
            }
    }
}
```

I tried to change ACTION_DOWN to ACTION_MOVE but it didn't work.

Here is my screen

[image]

Comment: this is more like algorithm question more then code, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040405/175554 explaining how.